# Unable to create order in back end

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2, admin-order-create, giftmessage

When I try to create an order from the sales grid I get a console error when trying to add the items to the order. `TypeError: newPopupContainer is null` in **giftmessage.js** on line 160

Code snippet from that file:

```
var newPopupContainer = $('gift_options_configure_new');
 $(document.body).insert({top: newPopupContainer});
 newPopupContainer.id = 'gift_options_configure';
```

I have compared that file to the same from a fresh installation package and there is no difference.

Any ideas on how to get round this?

Comment: maybe this `gift_options_configure_new` element not exist on that page.

Comment: it's there <div id="gift_options_configure_new" class="gift_options-popup product-configure-popup" style="display: none;">

Comment: If I hard refresh my browser the items are added OK :/

Comment: I also have to refresh my browser to show delivery options so something isn't quite right somewhere